# How to install self signed certificate for Google ARC "detached" app?

Tags: windows, web-services, google-chrome, rest-client, self-signed

I have just noticed that Google changed its ARC app to be detached from Chrome browser. I am getting this error (see screenshot below):

**Install self signed certificate in Chrome
The app cen't work if the self-signed certificate is not installed in Chrome.**

How can I get around it in Windows? thanks.

[image: Google ARC detached]